# Haskell - Count occurrences from multiple elements and return tuple

Tags: haskell, recursion

Heyy, I'm Haskell beginner and I pretend to do the following function:

occurrences  3 7 [-1,3,-4,3,4,3,-8,7,7,3]

Output that I want:
(4,2)

I made this try but doesn't worked so well, guess I having troubles to count the elements individually and to return the tuple

```
occurrences  a b [] = 0

occurrences  a b (x:xs) 
                       | x == a =  1 + occurrences  a b xs
                       | x == b =  1 + occurrences  a b xs
                       | otherwise = occurrences  a b xs
```

I appreciate any tip and help, thanks ;)

Comment: You're conceptually very close - you just seem to be confusing the tuple with the numeric values contained in it. As a hint, try pattern matching on `occurrences a b xs`.

Comment: Your base case is also wrong as you're returning a number rather than a tuple. That's very easy to fix though.

Comment: yeah, I see that I can fix the base case with ```occurrences  a b [] = 0 ```, but I couldnt find a way to fix the pattern matching to sum to only one tuple member...

Comment: The function will count how many `a`s and `b`s there are, so the sum of the two.

Comment: What if `a` and `b` are equal. So `occurrenses 3 3 [-1,3,-4,3,4,3,-8,7,7,3]`?

Answer (score 3):

A good approach is to add a type signature, and use the error messages to guide you:

```
occurrences :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
occurrences a b [] = 0
occurrences a b (x:xs)
  | x == a = 1 + occurrences a b xs
  | x == b = 1 + occurrences a b xs
  | otherwise = occurrences a b xs
```

The first error is “Could not deduce `(Num (Int, Int))` arising from the literal `0` from the context `Eq a`”. This means that we can’t use `0` in the first equation because it’s not a tuple, or more precisely, there is no `Num` instance that allows us to convert from the literal `0` to a tuple via `fromIntegral`. In the base case, we should return a tuple containing 0 for *both* sums:

```
occurrences :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
occurrences a b [] = (0, 0)
occurrences a b (x:xs)
  | x == a = 1 + occurrences a b xs
  | x == b = 1 + occurrences a b xs
  | otherwise = occurrences a b xs
```

The next error is “Could not deduce `(Num (Int, Int))` arising from a use of `+` from the context `Eq a`. This means we’re trying to use `+` on the result of `occurrences`, but as with the previous error, it doesn’t have a `Num` instance to provide `+`, because it’s now a tuple. The fix here is to match on the result of `occurrences` and add to the first or second element of the tuple accordingly:

```
occurrences :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
occurrences a b [] = (0, 0)
occurrences a b (x:xs)
  | x == a = let (m, n) = occurrences a b xs in (m + 1, n)
  | x == b = let (m, n) = occurrences a b xs in (m, n + 1)
  | otherwise = occurrences a b xs
```

Now this produces the expected result:

```
> occurrences 'a' 'b' "ababcb"
(2,3)
```

But we can improve this solution in a few ways. First, `a` and `b` remain the same throughout the computation, so we can do the recursion in a helper function instead of passing `a` and `b` around to every call.

```
occurrences :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
occurrences a b = go
  where
    go [] = (0, 0)
    go (x:xs)
      | x == a = let (m, n) = go xs in (m + 1, n)
      | x == b = let (m, n) = go xs in (m, n + 1)
      | otherwise = go xs
```

The idiom here is to define `f a b … = go where go = …`, and replace calls to `f a b …` with `go`—because they’re defined as equal! This is a great example of equational reasoning, replacing one side of an equation with the other.

Finally, since every equation of `go` except the base case contains a tail call to `go`, it suggests we can express this pattern of recursion with a *fold*. Here, our accumulator is the pair of results, and the combining function can increment the results accordingly as we step through the list. Since our accumulator is just a pair of integers, it’s a good idea to use a *strict* fold (`foldl'`).

```
import Data.List (foldl')

occurrences :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
occurrences a b = foldl' go (0, 0)
  where
    go (m, n) x
      | x == a = (m + 1, n)
      | x == b = (m, n + 1)
      | otherwise = (m, n)
```

Finally, instead of keeping an accumulator and adding elements one by one, we can just map each element to a value (0 or 1) and reduce them by summation. This map/reduce pattern is captured by `foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m`, which maps each element of a container (`t a`) to a value (`m`) and combines the results using a `Monoid` instance. The monoid to use here is `Sum` from `Data.Monoid`, whose `Monoid` and `Semigroup` instances define `mempty` = `Sum 0` and `Sum a <> Sum b` = `Sum (a + b)` respectively.

```
import Data.Coerce (coerce)
import Data.Foldable (foldMap)
import Data.Monoid (Sum(..))

occurrences :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
occurrences a b = coerce . foldMap go
  where
    go x
      | x == a = (Sum (1 :: Int), mempty)
      | x == b = (mempty, Sum (1 :: Int))
      | otherwise = mempty
```

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of functions like [**`first :: Arrow a => a b c -> a (b, d) (c, d)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:first) and [**`second :: Arrow a => a b c -> a (d, b) (d, c)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:second) to construct a tuple where we apply a function to one of the two items of the 2-tuple. For example:

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> first (1+) (1,4)
(2,4)
Prelude Control.Arrow> second (1+) (1,4)
(1,5)
```

We thus can use this to update the tuple with:

```
import Control.Arrow(first, second)
import Data.List(foldl')

occurrences :: (Eq a, Integral i, Integral j, Foldable f) => a -> a -> f a -> (i, j)
occurrences a b = foldl' (flip f) (0, 0)
    where f c | a == c = first (1+)
              | b == c = second (1+)
              | otherwise = id
```

For the sample input, this produces:

```
Prelude Control.Arrow Data.List> occurrences 3 7 [-1,3,-4,3,4,3,-8,7,7,3]
(4,2)
```

We can easily extent this behavior, by making use of lenses to update one of the elements of tuple.

Answer (score 1):

@emg184 gave a good way to solve this problem, but there could be cleaner, easier to read ways to go about doing this. For example:

```hs
occurrences x y xs = (count x xs, count y xs)
    where count = (length .) . filter . (==)
```

`count` could also be written in a more readable:

```hs
count x = (length . filter (== x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this problem a lot of different way's here is an example of doing it with a fold.

```
occurrences :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
occurrences a b list = foldr (\y (a', b') -> ((isEqual y a a'), (isEqual y b b'))) (0, 0) list
  where isEqual listEle tupEle count = if (listEle == tupEle) then (count + 1) else count
```

One of the problem's is you have a type mismatch. you want a type of:

```
(Int, Int)
```

Yet you are returning a type of int here once you have an empty list:

```
occurrences  a b [] = 0 -- Int 
occurrences  a b (x:xs) 
                       | x == a =  1 + occurrences  a b xs 
                       | x == b =  1 + occurrences  a b xs
                       | otherwise = occurrences  a b xs
```

You need some type of an accumulator you could do this by where binding a local function that takes your starting tuple of `(0, 0)` or you could pass it to occurrences like this:

```
occurrences :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
```

I would suggest using a local function since you'll always want to start with (0, 0) in this approach.

```
occurrences' :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
occurrences' a b list = go list (0,0)
  where go x (e1, e2) = if (x == []) then (e1, e2) else (go (tail x) ((isEqual a (head x) e1), (isEqual b (head x) e2)))
        isEqual v v' accum = if (v == v') then (accum + 1) else (accum)
```

This isnt the most idiomatic way to do it but it shows the point. You should try to use types to help with this.,